# Unable to access Container url in Bluemix for Spring Boot Application

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, devops, ibm-cloud-tools

I am using Toolchain in IBM Bluemix for deploying an Simple Spring boot application. 
In Delivery pipeline I have added 3 stages:

### Stage-1(Maven Build)

Fetching source code from git repo and building with Maven to build jar file

### Stage-2(Building Docker Image)

In this stage it is reading from a Dockerfile in source code and building a Docker image. In this stage Builder Type is "**IBM Container Service**".

### Stage-3(Container Deploy)

In this stage I am deploying the image in Container in Bluemix. Here Deployer Type is "**IBM Container Service**".

After all stages are completed successfully I hit the container ip provided in deploy stage but it gives an error

***A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.***

I have checked the container status with ***bx ic inspect some-container-name***
it shows container status running.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with the application.  You can investigate by either doing `bx ic logs some-container-name` or by connecting to the running container by doing `bx ic exec -it some-container-name /bin/bash`

Edit: You should also make sure you are specifying the correct port in the Container Deploy stage and when trying to connect to the IP address.